# Markers not loading in Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am able to load markers from a local database I include in my Ionic app that is just a simple array of lat/lon coords. The trouble is when I try and load them from a JSON file on the web. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

this is the call I use:

```
get('assets/data/markers.json')
```

And that all works fine for populating the map from a local data file.

Now my issue is that I would like to display markers from a JSON file that is located at :

http://app.toronto.ca/cc_sr_v1_app/data/edc_eventcal_APR?limit=500

Although when I change the get request to include that link as such:

```
get('http://app.toronto.ca/cc_sr_v1_app/data/edc_eventcal_APR?limit=500')
```

It gives me the following error message:

[image]

I believe I am not parsing the coords correctly in my marker function, yet I am unsure how to do this with the JSON array. Here is a visual of what the location structure looks like in the file:

[image]

My **home.ts** marker map/marker functionality:

```
displayGoogleMap(){
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.653908,-79.384293);
let mapOptions = {
center:latLng,
zoom:12,
mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
}


getMarkers(){
//this.http.get('assets/data/markers.json').map((res)=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
  this.http.get('http://app.toronto.ca/cc_sr_v1_app/data/edc_eventcal_APR? limit=500').map((res)=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
 this.addMarkersMap(data);

});
}

addMarkersMap(markers){
for(let marker of markers){
  var loc = {lat: marker.latitude , lon: marker.longitude};

  console.log(loc);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: loc,
  map: this.map,
  //title:marker.name,
 //label:marker.content

});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing non-existing key from marker object. Try to change below function.

```
addMarkersMap(markers)
{
    for(let marker of markers)
    {
        var loc = {lat: marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'].lat , lon: lat: marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'].lng};

        console.log(loc);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: loc,
        map: this.map
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: it says cannot find name "lat" with a red error line beneath in that call... with one under the "." between marker.calEvent as well...

Comment: but only in the second section with "lon:"  ... nothing showing for an error on "lat:" ..

Comment: I fixed it, think was just a typo . now I'm getting error "
google is not defined"

Comment: actually now its just giving me the original error again. No clue what Is going on here

Comment: but it shows the object with the lat and lon info under each array error this time

Comment: seems to be working only for the first lat long from the JSON file then stays the same for every other